# Combining spatial input with a label as input for CNN using Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a network set-up similar to [this Google Deepmind paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjr06PXiKvdAhVEJVAKHSdfCuQQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeepmind.com%2Fdocuments%2F227%2Fconsistent_generative_query_networks.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2-n9e1k3pL1Hbn0QNawf99). Their network set-up is as follows:

[image]

M<sub>θ</sub> is a convolutional network, so I was wondering how they concatenate the input frames with the viewpoints? As far as I knew, the CNN takes into account the spatial information right? So does it even make sense to concatenate the frames with the viewpoints as an input for the CNN?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Question was answered at [Stack Exchange Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38084/combining-spatial-input-with-a-label-as-input-for-cnn-using-keras)